# QML How to rotate image like the background shelf image of MacOSX dock

Tags: image, qml

The background image of the MacOS Dock (and many such clones) is a "shelf" in 3d perspective.

That is if you took a regular rectangle and had it "fall backwards" in 3d space.

For example: http://www.loneblacksheep.pro/image/Download/Dock.gif

Is it possible to do this with a QML Image rotation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at QML [`Rotation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-rotation.html) Item.

You can set the rotation origin to your `Rectangle` lower border center, and then rotate on the x-axis.

---

*Edit:*

```
Rectangle {
  id: myDock
  width: 500
  height: 50
  color: "red"

  transform: Rotation {

    // Transform origin is the middle point of the lower border
    origin {
      x: myDock.width / 2
      y: myDock.height
    }

    axis {x: 1; y: 0; z: 0}
    angle: 45
  }

}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post a code snippet of this. When I tried to set the rotation origin like this `origin.x: Item.Bottom` then only the right side of my rectangle is rotating correctly. The left side is normal?

Comment: Thanks TheHuge_. Working nicely I was missing setting the origin.y to be the height of the Rectangle (or image).